# Incorrect UUID format in component c#

Tags: c#

I need help with the next code, that throws the exception
Error emitting 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute' attribute -- 'Incorrect UUID format.'

```
[GuidAttribute(Discover.CLASS_DiscoverPlugin)]
public class Discover : TCustomDiscoverPlugin
{

    public const string CLASS_TenderDialogePlugin = "{CB19D13D-C194-49f1-B1A0-75B49283CFC8}";
    public const string CLASS_DiscoverPlugin = "{6111098C-B821-432d-9EC3-146BF5D1C276}";

    public override Object PluginGUIDs()
    {
        string[] classIDs = new string[1];
        classIDs[1] = CLASS_TenderDialogePlugin;
        return classIDs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Get rid of the braces - this compiles with no problems:

```
[GuidAttribute("CB19D13D-C194-49f1-B1A0-75B49283CFC8")]
```

It's a shame the accepted formats aren't documented, mind you :(